# Ruby Sequel model to have validation for create and not update

Tags: ruby, sequel

How I can I avoid having validation for `update` while having it for `create`? For instance:

I wish to have an `image` field to have `presence validation` on `create`. But want to avoid it in `edit` and assume the previous value in case of no change.

Note: I am using Padrino.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Sequel, validations are generally done at the instance level using the `validation_helpers` plugin.  So you just use a standard ruby conditional if you only want to validate it for new objects and not for existing ones:

```
plugin :validation_helpers
def validate
  super
  validates_presence :image if new?
end
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know that `new?` existed! Anyways great its a great ORM, thanks for it!

Answer (score 0):

you can say something like:

```
validates :image, :presence => true, on: :create
```

that means you will do validation only when do create.

Answer (score 0):

**In Rails,**

The "validates" keyword in Rails takes a parameter that allows you to do this:

```
validates :your_validator, :presence => true, :on => :create
```

You can also pass an array there:

```
validates :your_validator, :presence => true, :on => [:create, :update]
```

**In Padrino,**

I believe padrino using datamapper - DM has contextual validations. So, you could do a contextual validation.

```
validates :image, :presence => true, :when => [:custom]
```

Then while saving, you can do this:

```
post.save(:custom)
# OR
post.valid?(:custom)
```

The context :custom can be used in different places.

Comment: I think thats a Rails specific helper. I am using Padrino, my bad I should probably have mentioned.

Comment: I didn't expect it to be a Padrino model :) I have updated my answer. I believe Padrino uses datamapper.

Comment: No, Padrino is ORM agnostic and I am using Sequel. Thanks for answering anyway.